# Returning JSON from Java to Worklight Adapter

Tags: java, json, worklight-adapters

I have one class **FileHandling** in which there is one method called **readAllLayouts** which will read the all files from specified folder and return the content as JSONArray to worklight adapter.

I have got this type of Error when invoking worklight procedure:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Evaluator: Java class \"org.json.simple.JSONArray\" has no public instance field or method named \"isSuccessful\"."
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

and this is the code of my Java method:

```
public static JSONArray readAllLayoutFiles ( ){

    File layoutDir = new File( LAYOUT_PARENT_DIR );

    String allFiles[] = layoutDir.list();
    System.out.println( "All Files Length : " + allFiles.length );
    JSONObject obj = null;//new JSONObject[ allFiles.length ];

    JSONArray retArr = new JSONArray();

    for ( String f : allFiles ){
        obj= new JSONObject();
        obj.put( "layoutname", f.replaceAll (".txt", "" ) );
        obj.put( "layouthtml", readLayoutFile ( f ) );
        retArr.add(obj);
    }
    obj= new JSONObject();
    obj.put( "isSuccessful", true );
    retArr.add(obj);

    System.out.println( retArr.toString() );
    return retArr;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the problem I have changed my code that will working, but now It is not returning JSON but returning String that contains JSON.

Here is the code and Working Fine :

```
public static String readAllLayoutFiles ( ){

    File layoutDir = new File( LAYOUT_PARENT_DIR );

    String allFiles[] = layoutDir.list();
    System.out.println( "All Files Length : " + allFiles.length );
    JSONObject obj = null;//new JSONObject[ allFiles.length ];

    JSONArray retArr = new JSONArray();

    for ( String f : allFiles ){
        obj= new JSONObject();
        obj.put( "layoutname", f.replaceAll (".txt", "" ) );
        obj.put( "layouthtml", readLayoutFile ( f ) );
        retArr.add(obj);
    }
    obj= new JSONObject();
    obj.put( "isSuccessful", true );
    retArr.add(obj);

    System.out.println( retArr.toJSONString() );
    return retArr.toJSONString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is "isSuccessful" false in the output whereas it is set to true in your code?

Comment: I don't know about that.